# Angular UI Bootstrap pagination not working

Tags: pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui-Bootstrap pagination  but its not working  as expected I refer following post but its not working for me.

[How do I tell ui-Bootstrap what content to paginate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653427/how-do-i-tell-ui-bootstrap-what-content-to-paginate)

My code is as follows.

```
<div>
  <ul>
     <li ng-repeat= "payment in paymentHistory">
        <div >
          <div > 
            <p >payment.status</p> 
           </div>
           <div>
              <p >payment.cost</p>
           </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 <div ng-show="pagination"> <pagination total-items="totalItems" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></pagination></div>
```

My controller code:

```
paymentFactory.getPaymentHistory( )
.success(function (paymentHisInfo) {
     for(var i = 0; i< paymentHisInfo.list.length; i++){
      $scope.paymentHistory.push({
     "status":paymentHisInfo.list[i].status,
              "cost":paymentHisInfo.list[i].cost});
       }
       $scope.list = $scope.paymentHistory;
       $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
       $scope.currentPage = 1;
           $scope.pageCount=Math.ceil($scope.list.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
       $scope.list.$promise.then(function () {
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.list.length;

        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
        end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
                $scope.paymentHistory = $scope.list.slice(begin, end);
      });

    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log("error occured in getPaymentHistory");
    });
Please let me know whats wrong in my code
```

Comment: Its my bad..There was type in my code. I updated code which works fine.

Comment: You should answer your own question or delete this question.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

UIB Pagination is lightweight pagination directive that helps us to paginate our web project. To use Angular UI bootstrap pagination we can get the code form here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and can use in our project. 
To use we have HTML snippet to add in our project.

```
<pagination boundary-links="true" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="pageChanged()" ng-model="currentPage" total-items="totalPages">  </pagination>
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',    function ($scope) {
     $scope.maxSize = 5;
     $scope.currentPage = 1;
     $scope.totalPages = 20;

   $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        // operation to perform on page changed
        console.log("Hi I am on ",($scope.currentPage-1),"page")
    };
  }])
```

1) The **maxSize** is number page navigator on a page.

2) The **currentPage** is active page in HTML specified by ng-model.

3) The **totalPages** is number of all the pages.

4) **boundary-links**  is used to display. First and last page button and by default it is false.

4) **ng-change** call the operation on page change event.

Hope it helps.
Thanks,
Oodles Technologies