# Pagination doesn't work on angular-ui-bootstrap inside of a tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, pagination

I have this code http://plnkr.co/edit/thSwsookMIY6LZMftVhY?p=preview. I just tried put a pagination module of ui-bootstrap in a tab. My problem is that currentPage changes in the scope, but doesn't refresh the items that is showing.

**Controller List.js**

```
controllers.controller('List', function ($scope) {

    $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.totalAds = 0;

    $scope.pageCount = function () {
        return Math.ceil($scope.totalAds / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    };

    $scope.tabs = [
        { "category": "G", "active": true, "ads": [{ "title": "Tit 1 G", "content": "Content ad 1 g" }, { "title": "Tit 2 G", "content": "Content ad 2 g" }, { "title": "Tit 3 G", "content": "Content ad 3 g" }, { "title": "Tit 4 G", "content": "Content ad 4 g" }, { "title": "Tit 5 G", "content": "Content ad 5 g" }, { "title": "Tit 6 G", "content": "Content ad 6 g" }, { "title": "Tit 7 G", "content": "Content ad  7 g" }, { "title": "Tit 8 G", "content": "Content ad 8 g" }, { "title": "Tit 9 G", "content": "Content ad 9 g" }, { "title": "Tit 10 G", "content": "Content ad 10 g" }, { "title": "Tit 11 G", "content": "Content ad 11 g" }, { "title": "Tit 12 G", "content": "Content ad 12 g" }, { "title": "Tit 13 G", "content": "Content ad 13 g" }, { "title": "Tit 14 G", "content": "Content ad 14 g" }, { "title": "Tit 15 G", "content": "Content ad 15 g" }, { "title": "Tit 16 G", "content": "Content ad 16 g" }, { "title": "Tit 17 G", "content": "Content ad 17 g" }] },
        { "category": "C", "active": false, "ads": [{ "title": "Tit 1 C", "content": "Content ad 1 c" }, { "title": "Tit 2 C", "content": "Content ad 2 c" }, { "title": "Tit 3 C", "content": "Content ad 3 c" }] },
        { "category": "T", "active": false, "ads": [{ "title": "Tit 1 T", "content": "Content ad 1 t" }, { "title": "Tit 2 T", "content": "Content ad 2 t" }, { "title": "Tit 3 T", "content": "Content ad 3 t" }, { "title": "Tit 4 T", "content": "Content ad 4 t" }, { "title": "Tit 5 T", "content": "Content ad 5 t" }, { "title": "Tit 6 T", "content": "Content ad 6 t" }, { "title": "Tit 5 T", "content": "Content ad 5 t" }, { "title": "Tit 7 T", "content": "Content ad 7 t" }, { "title": "Tit 8 T", "content": "Content ad 8 t" }, { "title": "Tit 9 T", "content": "Content ad 9 t" }, { "title": "Tit 10 T", "content": "Content ad 10 t" }, { "title": "Tit 11 T", "content": "Content ad 11 t" }, { "title": "Tit 12 T", "content": "Content ad 12 t" }, { "title": "Tit 13 T", "content": "Content ad 13 t" }, { "title": "Tit 14 T", "content": "Content ad 14 t" }, { "title": "Tit 15 T", "content": "Content ad 15 t" }, { "title": "Tit 16 T", "content": "Content ad 16 t" }, { "title": "Tit 17 T", "content": "Content ad 17 t" }, { "title": "Tit 18 T", "content": "Content ad 18 t" }, { "title": "Tit 19 T", "content": "Content ad 19 t" }] },
        { "category": "A", "active": false, "ads": [{ "title": "Tit 1 A", "content": "Content ad 1 a" }, { "title": "Tit 2 A", "content": "Content ad 2 a" }] }
    ];

    $scope.getTotal = function () {
        $scope.totalAds = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function (tab) {
            if (tab.active) {
                $scope.totalAds = tab.ads.length;
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.selectedAds = function (category) {
        var ads = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function (tab) {
            if (tab.category == category) {
                ads = tab.ads;
            }
        });
        return ads;
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function () {
        console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
    };

    $scope.category = function () {
        return $scope.tabs.filter(function (tab) {
            return tab.active;
        })[0].category;
    };

    $scope.$watch('category()', function () {
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.getTotal();
        var end = $scope.currentPage + $scope.itemsPerPage;
        $scope.filteredAds = $scope.selectedAds($scope.category()).slice(0, end);   
    });

    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage),
         end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredAds = $scope.selectedAds($scope.category()).slice(begin, end);
    });

    $scope.getTotal();

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
        <head lang="es">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Adiminstración del tablón de anuncios</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.12/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="List.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="List">
              <tabset>
                    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.category}}" active="tab.active">
                      <ul>
                          <li ng-repeat="ad in filteredAds">
                              <section>
                                  <h3 ng-bind="ad.title"></h3>
                                  <p ng-bind="ad.content"></p>
                              </section>
                          </li>
                      </ul>
                      <pagination total-items="totalAds" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" ng-model="currentPage"></pagination>
                      <p>
                          Total items: {{totalAds}}<br />
                          Items per page: {{itemsPerPage}}<br />
                          Current Page: {{currentPage}}
                      </p>
                    </tab>
              </tabset>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried the solution that been posted here ([How do I tell ui-Bootstrap what content to paginate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653427/how-do-i-tell-ui-bootstrap-what-content-to-paginate)) but it doesn't work for me. The value currentPage refresh in the page but the $watch doesn't fired.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue i faced and got it solved by little changes in the code. This is because tabset uses its own controller and the parent controller of pagination becomes tabset's controller.

In your controller add:

```
$scope.data = {};
```

In the Template change ng-model to:

```
<pagination ng-model='data.currentPage'></pagination>
```